# How to install Qt6 on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: apt, application-development, 21.10, qt, libraries

When trying to open a program that requires Qt6, it gives `error while loading shared libraries: libQt6Network.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. I tried installing Qt6 by going to the [Qt website](https://www.qt.io/download) -> Downloads for open source users -> Download the Qt Online Installer -> Qt Online Installer for Linux (64-bit), then in the installer itself I selected "Qt 6.2 for desktop development". After it'd finished installing I restarted and tried to open the program again, and it still gave the same error. I'd also seen `sudo apt install qt6-base-dev` be suggested so I tried that, but that just gives the error `Unable to locate package qt6-base-dev`, so now I'm not sure what else I could try.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`libqt6network6` is indeed part of the `qt6-base-dev` meta-package and you can install it like so:

```
sudo apt install qt6-base-dev
```

However, unfortunately, this meta-package is not available for Ubuntu 21.10. It is currently available only for [Ubuntu 22.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=qt6-base-dev&searchon=names)

Comment: @Foxes Either you upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 **which I strongly recommend** ... or you go the ["at your own risk way"](https://askubuntu.com/q/1170054) :)

Answer (score 3):

You might try to use [Owen Kirby's backport of Qt6](https://bugs.launchpad.net/%7Eokirby/+archive/ubuntu/qt6-backports):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:okirby/qt6-backports
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qt6-base-dev [...]
```

Just like @Raffa, I also strongly recommend the update to Ubuntu 22.04, and Owen Kirby's backports are perhaps not the most up to date (6.2.2 at the time of writing; it's a LTS version; the most recent version of Qt 6 is 6.3.1), but it should get you going