# Install qt6 on 22.04

Tags: 22.04, qt, libraries

I am trying to install qt6 on Ubuntu 22.04. I have found this answer -> [How to install Qt6 on Ubuntu 21.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404353/how-to-install-qt6-on-ubuntu-21-10) where it states that package qt6-base-dev is available on 22.04.
However, I get `Unable to locate package qt6-base-dev` when trying to install it

Comment: [qt6-base-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/qt6-base-dev) is indeed available in 22.04. Make sure the Universe repository is anabled.

Comment: @Nmath I am trying to install qt6 on ubuntu 22.04, I had only qtchooser which didn't provide version 6

Comment: @mikewhatever It worked! Thank you. Do you want to post it as an answer with explanation why it worked, so I can mark as resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[qt6-base-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/qt6-base-dev) is indeed available in 22.04. It is in the Universe repository, so do make sure it is [enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository).

...and then:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qt6-base-dev
```